# Detection of an optical noise with a photodetector, noise-equivalent power (NEP)

Tags: optics, signal-processing, noise

I am trying to find the minimum power that can be detected by a photodetector for which I know its noise-equivalent power (NEP).

The standard formulas are:

$$\mathrm{SNR} = \frac{\langle i_s^2(t)\rangle}{\langle i_\mathrm{th}^2\rangle},$$

where $\langle i_s^2(t)\rangle$ is the mean-square signal current and $\langle i_\mathrm{th}^2\rangle$ is the mean-square current due to the photodetector's thermal noise, which is the dominant noise at low light intensity. We can express the thermal noise:

$$\langle i_\mathrm{th}^2\rangle = \tilde{\rho}_{\mathrm{pd}}^2\cdot B \cdot \left(\mathrm{NEP}\right)^2,$$

where $\tilde{\rho}_{\mathrm{pd}}$ is the photodetector responsivity (in units A/W), $\mathrm{NEP}$ is the photodetector's noise equivalent power and $B$ is the detection bandwidth.

So far, so good. My problem comes with $\langle i_s^2(t)\rangle$. I now consider the detection of an optical signal that is the noise coming from an erbium-doped amplifier (EDFA), having a certain optical power spectral density $S$ (expressed in W/Hz). Let's consider $S$ independent of frequency to simplify. I want to know how much I can attenuate this optical signal(that is actually noise) before I am no longer able to detect it with my detector (SNR <1). I am allowed any bandwidth I want at detection. I ignore here the effect of photons(shot noise). According to the formula for the SNR, the smaller the bandwidth $B$, the higher the SNR, so in principle for any input power, I can always reduce sufficiently my bandwidth to detect the signal.

But if we reduce the bandwidth, intuitively I think that we will filter the electrical power spectral density and decrease $\langle i_s^2(t)\rangle$ as well. So it looks that the bandwidth will have no effect. This is my intuition, is it correct? and if yes, how to compute $\langle i_s^2(t)\rangle$ in function of the bandwidth ?

EDIT: According to "The Photon", I am right and $\langle i_s^2(t)\rangle$ is proportional to the bandwidth. Then I have an additional, related question: I detect such a signal with an optical spectrum analyzer (OSA) and I have a choice of sensitivity levels (normal, high-sens1, high-sens2,...). I am guessing that these higher sensitivities decrease the detection bandwidth (e.g. by averaging). Thus, when I detect my EDFA noise with the OSA, I would expect that when I choose a higher sensitivity, both the signal and the noise should go down. However, when I do it, only the noise goes down but the signal remains at the same level (I keep the resolution bandwidth at the same value). How is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

> According to the formula for the SNR, the smaller the bandwidth $B$, the higher the SNR, so in principle for any input power, I can always reduce sufficiently my bandwidth to detect the signal.

This is true if changing the bandwidth reduces $\langle i_{th}^2(t)\rangle$ more than it reduces $\langle i_s^2(t)\rangle$. This isn't an uncommon scenario in communications systems, or if you want to detect a optical source modulated with a single sinusoidal tone.

But you are trying to detect a white noise source (because you assumed $S$ is independent of frequency).

In this case when you reduce your receiver bandwidth, you will reduce your "signal" by just as much as you reduce your receiver's noise.

> But if we reduce the bandwidth, intuitively I think that we will filter the electrical power spectral density and decrease $\langle i_s^2(t)\rangle$ as well. So it looks that the bandwidth will have no effect.

Agreed.

> how to compute $\langle i_s^2(t)\rangle$ in function of the bandwidth ?

Because you have a white noise source, $\langle i_s^2(t)\rangle$ is proportional to bandwidth.